# AlloyUI Scheduler

Tags: yui, scheduler, yui3, alloy-ui

I have played around with the AlloyUI Scheduler, and it seems to be the by far best calendar out there. While poking it, a few questions have risen. I am not particularly experienced with YUI, so my questions might be caused by lack of experience with the kind of thinking that goes with YUI. Nevertheless, here are the problems I haven't managed to overcome:

1. First, I tried loading 500+ events into it, and the result is that every action (adding events, deleting events, switching between views, switching between weeks/months) happens with a delay. Is this expected? 500 events doesn't sound like much, even for a relatively short period.
2. Can I limit the hours displayed in Day or Month view? I.e., instead of 00:00 - 23:59 I'd prefer to only display 08:00 - 17:59.
3. I've managed to translate bits of the UI, such as "Today", "Day", "Week", "Month", "Agenda", "Delete", "Save", "Cancel", "e.g., Dinner at Brian's". But how can I translate the days (e.g., "Monday", "Tuesday" etc)?
4. I've found a way to replace the default buttons of the EventRecorder's toolbar. But is there a way to keep the originals ("Save", "Cancel", "Delete") and add a few custom ones?

   ```
   var eventRecorder = new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder({
     toolbar: {
       children: [
         [
           {
             label: 'Details',
             on: {
               click: function () {
                 alert("Yeah!");
               }
             }
           },
         ]
       ]
     }
   });
   ```
5. Is there a way to disable some periods of time for event creation? I'd imagine this could be achieved by interrupting the event creation by some way. Something in the lines of

   ```
   scheduler.on({
     'scheduler-events:add': function (event) {
       return isEventAllowed();
     }
   });
   ```
6. What is the correct way for accessing the calendar event data in the case of events such as "scheduler-event:change", "scheduler-event-recorder:edit" or similar? I currently use `scheduler.getEvents()[event.index]._state.data` and `eventRecorder.getUpdatedSchedulerEvent()._state.data`, respectively. But using these smells funny.
7. What would be a recommended way for adding a detailed editing view for events? I currently hacked it with something in the lines of

   ```
   scheduler.on({
     'scheduler-base:click': function(event) {
       var toolbar = $(".aui-scheduler-event-recorder-overlay .yui3-widget-ft .aui-toolbar-content .aui-btn-group");
       if (!toolbar.data("custom-processed")) {
         var button = $('<button class="aui-btn">Details</button>');
         toolbar.append(button);
         button.click(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var eventData = (eventRecorder.get("event") || eventRecorder.clone())._state.data;
           // Creating my detailed editing window here
           $(".aui-scheduler-event-recorder-overlay").addClass("yui3-overlay-hidden");
         });
         toolbar.data("custom-processed", true);
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Thanks,

Comment: I have the same questions too, do you know how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: No, that part of development has been descoped, but I too am still interested in the solutions.

Comment: You should split this into multiple questions.

Comment: I have answered a question related to #4 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280868/how-can-i-add-a-customized-buttons-to-the-alloyui-schedulers-event-popup/26089048#26089048).

Comment: I have explained how to completely internationalize the `Scheduler` (answering #3) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781072/how-to-localize-the-alloyui-scheduler-component/46439216#46439216).

Comment: For #5, you could check whether a time is allowed and cancel the [`ScheduleEventRecorder` `save` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053982/save-edit-delete-and-cancel-events-in-alloyui-scheduler) with [`Event.halt()`](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/EventFacade.html#method_halt) to ensure events cannot be saved at certain times. Something like this should work:
`eventRecorder: new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder({ on: { save: function(event) { if (!isEventAllowed()) { this.hidePopover();
 alert('An event cannot be scheduled at that time.'); event.halt(); } }
 }`

Comment: I have answered a question related to #6 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053982/save-edit-delete-and-cancel-events-in-alloyui-scheduler).